# Which technique is used in Auto Answering user queries in Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have a paragraph, system has to understand it and it should answer all the questions asked by the user. Please name the techniques and methodologies.

Comment: i think there should be two database, one for match question & second for answer. read it https://www.wired.com/2016/03/google-inbox-auto-answers-emails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on the problem that you are trying to solve, the data available to you and the underlying domain. Lets get to it one by one:

**Type of Problem**
There are multiple types of question answering systems, like one word answers based on extract the exact answer from various sentences, or returning the most similar sentence from a list of sentences based on the question asked by the user, using various similarity and embedding techniques. I think this paper : [Teaching Machines to Read and Comprehend](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03340) should be a good place to start getting an idea about such systems.

**Dataset**
Next comes the dataset for such systems. Now there are various datasets available for question answering systems like :

- [SQuAD dataset](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/)
- [QA dataset based on Wikipedia Articles](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/QA-data/)
- [Facebook bAbI dataset](https://research.fb.com/downloads/babi/)
- [AllenAI dataset based elementary Science question](http://allenai.org/data.html)
- [NewsQA datset](https://datasets.maluuba.com/NewsQA)

**Methodologies**
Well there are multiple ways to go about solving this problem. It would be difficult to list all of them in one answer, but I can provide you some references:

- [Deep Learning for Question Answering](http://cs.umd.edu/~miyyer/data/deepqa.pdf)
- [Various Deep Learning models on Question answering](https://www.slideshare.net/sujitpal/deep-learning-models-for-question-answering)
- [SquAD dataset Leaderboard](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/)
- [Question Answering based on Word Alignment](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02628)
- [Attention Based Question Answering](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/reports/2761224.pdf)
- [Reasoning-based QA](http://ai2-website.s3.amazonaws.com/publications/tableilp_ijcai_2016.pdf)